# Getting exit code of a process NOT started by powershell (exit code from get-process cmdlet)

Tags: windows, powershell, installation, silent

Fair warning, I'm a powershell n00b and this is my first script, however I haven't been able to find an answer after 2 days of research (maybe I lack the proper terminology?) so I pledge to the experts!

While doing a PW script to control the silent install of an app, I have two processes to watch for: The first setup.exe that makes some decisions and based on the result, launches either of 2 separate setup.exe. My script has to launch the first setup.exe, let it do its thing, then get the exit codes of both setup.exe, and while I have no issues getting the exit code of the first one, I can't find how to do the same for the second one.

My script looks like this:

```
$LogFile = [PathToMyLog]\MyLog.log
$SetupPath = c:\Users\[MyUsername]\Desktop\Setup.exe


#This part runs the first setup and gets the exit code.

$FirstSetup = Start-Process -filepath $SetupPath -passthru
$SetupID = $FirstSetup.id
wait-process -id $SetupID
$FirstExitCode = FirstSetup.exitCode
add-content  $LogFile "Return Code for the first setup is: $FirstExitCode"

#This second part gets the other setup.exe process and tries to find its
exit code

If ($ExitCode -eq 0 -or -eq 3010)
{
    Do
    {
        Start-Sleep -seconds 2
        $SecondSetup = Get-Process -name Setup -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $SecondSetupID = $SecondSetup.id
    }
    Until ($SetupID -ne $SecondSetupID -and -$SecondSetupID -ne $null)

    Wait-Process -inputobject $SecondSetup
    $SecondExitCode = $SecondSetup.ExitCode
    add-content  $LogFile "Return Code for the Second setup is: $SecondExitCode"
    If ($SecondExitCode -eq 0 -or -eq 3010)
    {
        add-content  $LogFile "Install completed successfully"
    }
    Else
    {
        add-content  $LogFile "Install failed at the second Setup.exe stage"
        Exit $SecondExitCode
    }
}
else
{
add-content  $LogFile "Install failed at the first Setup.exe stage"
Exit $FirstExitCode
```

After executing it,my `$SecondExitCode` variable is always empty (and thus the `if` block goes through the "Install failed at second setup.exe stage" path.

Doing simpler testing (by trying to get a notepad.exe process exit code for example), if I launch the notepad.exe from **within** the script by using `start-process`, I can always get the exit code when closing it, however if I launch notepad manually and then use a `Get-process` cmdlet, I do get a process object with ID, path and all the good stuff, **except** exit code.

I tried using `waitforExit()` instead (with a `Write-Verbose $process.exitCode` line afterwards), but it errors out like this:

```
>     Write-Verbose : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Message' because it is null.
>     At line:7 char:15
>     + Write-Verbose $notepad.exitcode
>     +               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>         + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Write-Verbose], ParameterBindingValidationException
>         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteVerboseCommand
```

Why is this happening? I thought all process objects were equal, regardless who started them. And how can I then get this pesky exit code for the second setup.exe?

P.S. I'm running with PW 4.0

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, it started working by itself once I allowed enough time for windows update to run (I was working on a VM which was constantly being reverted back to the base image snapshot). After letting it sit overnight and restarting, I got the "Wait while updates are being installed" window, and after that my `get-process` process object was able to see the `.ExitCode` property without issues.

It's unexpected but makes sense.